# Человек, манипулирующий фактами, - синоним (научн.)

Tags: синонимы

Обычно такую манеру общения держат юристы с противоположенной стороны, политики.

Answer (score 3):

**Демагог**

*Тот, кто в рассуждениях, спорах, высказываниях использует пустые, не основанные на фактах фразы.*

> «И где такие виданы министры?
>      Кто так из них толпе кадить бы мог?
>    Я допущу: успехи наши быстры,
>   Но где ж у нас министер-демагог?»

Comment: А можно ли манипулировать фактами, "не основываясь" на таковых?

Comment: @Alex_ander Спасибо, что следите за моими ответами. Эта фраза основана на фактах? Да, вы написали мне комментарий, значит как минимум один мой ответ прочитали. Является ли первая фраза демагогией? Да, так как фактов для такого вывода недостаточно. Софистика лишь один из вариантов демагогии.

Answer (score 0):

Вития - кружева в описании. Краснобай - красное словцо прежде всего. Всезнайка - блещет кругозором и этим хочет задавить собеседника. Шельмец  - подменяет понятия разными способами.

Answer (score 0):

**Подтасовщик**

> Ушаков: «Тот, кто подтасовывает факты с целью ввести в заблуждение».
>
> Энциклопедический словарь: «Тот, кто искажает, превратно истолковывает какие-л. сведения, данные». *Подтасовщик фактов*.

Но это разговорное слово.

Comment: Формально этому слову соответствует _софист._ https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_philosophy/1128/%D0%A1%D0%9E%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%97%D0%9C

Comment: Хороший вариант! Удовлетворяет всем требованиям. Сам пытался вспомнить такое слово, но в голове вместо *софизма* вертелась *апория*.

Answer (score 0):

Ещё в копилку синонимов набрёл на **крючкотворство** и **крючкотворец**.
Но ответ @Alex_ander (данный в комментарии) про софиста - очень уж точено подходит к научному термину!